# How am I supposed to send my REST Api response from android back to the IBM watson?

Tags: android, rest, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am designing android chatbot using watson. I have a usecase where I need to call external REST api. So I define the function name and parameters in the action tag of JSON editor. I receive those variables in my android code through conversation Api. My question is how am I suppose to send my REST Api response back to the watson? I know I have to use /message api in which I need to set a context. And initially I get the context from the MessageResponse class after the conversation API gets executed. And how are we going to let Watson know about the rest api response. How do we link that response to watson? Help me with some code if you can.

Comment: What code did you look at so far, what have you tried?

Comment: I have their android-chatbot sample. But it doesn't include this usecase in which there is an external Rest api call on client side. Updating Watson with that response is all I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

For calling external REST API it is recommended to use [Cloud Functions](https://console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/)  - in the implementation of the cloud function you create the API request you need. Then in `Watson Assitant` you add the `"action"` field where you specify what of your cloud function to call and where to store the result (the result will be stored to some variable in the `"context"` field). More info in the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html) about how to make programatic calls from a dialog node.

Comment: One of the IBM developer told me to avoid using Cloud Functions as they are not recommended as of now. I was shocked but yeah that is the truth.

Comment: Well, I use Cloud functions regularly and they work fine for me. Of course it always depend what are you using them for for but for external REST API calls I believe they are fine.